# how many hexagons can be found in the graph?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

[image]

At first sight I thought that this question requires considering different cases, but I find it difficult to convince myself as to how to start this question. Could someone please give me some hints?

Comment: Think of the ways you can make a six-sided figure with squares. You need at least three. Four would work. Five would work. Six will not in this arrangement. So how many ways can we make "3-hexagons"? What about 4 and 5?

Comment: @TerraHyde Hi. I'm sorry I don't understand. What is meant by 'all or parts of one of the straight lines in the diagram'? Is it okay to only have vertex at each side?

Comment: What it appears to mean is that you can't have diagonals or "half-squares".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways to make a hexagon from squares in this configuration are:

```
 _____   ________   ________
|__|__| |__|__|__| |__|__|__|
|__|    |__|       |__|__|
```

As well as the rotations of each of these. This means there are $4$ of each of the 4-hexagons and 5-hexagons.

For the 3-hexagons, we know there must be at least six (placing the corner in each of the six original squares), but the middle two squares could have the horizontal part going left OR going right, so they each have two possibilities. This brings us to $8$ of the 3-hexagons.

So the total is $16$.

---

EDIT:

To make it a little clearer, consider the ways you can pick one, two, three, four, or five of the squares so that they are connected along the edges:

```
 __   _____   _____   ________   ________
|__| |__|__| |__|__| |__|__|__| |__|__|__|
             |__|    |__|       |__|__|

 ________   ________   _____   ________
|__|__|__| |__|__|__| |__|__| |__|__|__|
           |__|  |__| |__|__|    |__|

 _____
|__|__|__
   |__|__|
```

And any reflections/rotations of these. Notice that only the ones from the first set (from the original answer) are six-sided. This means that we don't need to worry with the remaining figures.

So we can identify all the hexagons just by placing the three from the top in all the various spots:

```
+-- ++- ++- -+- -+- -++ -++ --+
++- +-- -+- ++- -++ -+- --+ -++

--+ +-- +++ +++ +++ +++ -++ ++-
+++ +++ +-- --+ ++- -++ +++ +++
```

In this diagram, pluses are squares you want, and minuses are squares you don't.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why are there only the three configurations ?

Comment: One square has four sides. Two squares together will still have four sides. Three squares will either be a 3x1 rectangle or the shape I gave. Four will be one of the tetris shapes, of which, only the L pieces are hexagons. Five will either be the one I gave or a u shape. Six must be the whole rectangle.

Comment: How could you decide whether one can find hexagons in 1 or 2 squares or not? I still do not understand the argument using sides. Isn't there 7 sides when 2 squares are used?

Comment: As soon as I get back to my computer, I will update this answer with a fuller demonstration of what I was trying to communicate. Sorry that I have yet to be able to communicate it clearly.